# jQuery touch event in iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, events, mobile-safari

I want to do like that when i clicked on image it will display alert.

which jquery code is apply for touch event on iPad?

I already use this code but it is not working. I also try this to put code in `$(document).on('touchstart',function(){});` but in that also it is not working.

```
            $('.img.shape').on('tap', function () {
                alert('fdsadsfaf');
            });
```

how to do it?

Comment: Your image have a img class?

Comment: can  you add your html element here

Answer (score -1):

Check if the element exists. It already happened to me that the touchstart event does not work on Ipad 10.5, I had to insert an onclick on the element by calling the js function